# Trouble saving non-html emails with python Google API

Tags: python, html, gmail, gmail-api

Started learning python last week and thought a good project would be something that automatically takes all unread emails from all my inboxes, and display them in another window with access control of my inbox.
Gotta start at beginning though so I am working on getting a folder, which will have a folder for each email, containing the content of the email. Many emails I can save as a .html and have no problem, however some do not work that way, and end up saving nothing. How can I save these more complex emails?
example : a linkedin email will save as a .html and have all the job positions i was emailed, and it has the style of the actual email
problem example : a tiktok email, which contains pictures of videos people reposted, will not save anything, however if I download the email directly from gmail, I get a folder full of pngs, htmls, js.download, and file files.
Here is the code thanks for any help ❤️

```
import os
import pickle
# Gmail API utils
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
# for encoding/decoding messages in base64
from base64 import urlsafe_b64decode
from mimetypes import guess_type
from datetime import datetime

#Want all access, manage inbox
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
#emails
personal_email = 'personalemail@gmail.com'

#get autentication from gmail
def gmail_authenticate():
    creds = None
   #token.pickle has user's access and refresh tokens
    if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
        with open("token.pickle", "rb") as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
   #if token unaviable login
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        #Save credentials for next time
        with open("token.pickle", "wb") as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    return build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
    
#get unread emails
def get_unread_emails(service):
    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds=['UNREAD']).execute()
    messages = []
    if 'messages' in results:
        messages.extend(results['messages'])
    
    while 'nextPageToken' in results:
        page_token = results['nextPageToken']
        results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds=['UNREAD'],pageToken=page_token).execute()
        if 'messages' in results:
            messages.extend(results['messages'])
    return messages

#mark as read
def mark_as_read(service,message_ids):
    for message_id in message_ids:
        try:
            service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id = message_id, body ={'removeLabelIds' : ['UNREAD']}).execute()
        except HttpError as e:
            error = e.get_reason()
            if "Precondition check failed" in error:
                print(f"Failed to mark email {message_id} as read : Precondition check failed. Skipping...")
            else:
                raise
                
#output email parts
def output_parts(service, parts, folder_name, message):
    print("checking parts")
    if parts:
        print("has parts")
        for part in parts:
            save_part(service,part,folder_name,message)

            if part.get("parts"):
                output_parts(service, part.get("parts"), folder_name, message)

def save_part(service,part,folder_name,message):
    filename = part.get("filename")
    mimeType = part.get("mimeType")
    body = part.get("body")
    data = body.get("data")
    part_headers = part.get("headers")
    print(mimeType)            
    if mimeType == "text/plain":
        if data:
            text = urlsafe_b64decode(data)
    elif mimeType == "text/html":
        if not filename:
            filename = "index.html"
        filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
        with open(filepath, "wb") as f:
            f.write(urlsafe_b64decode(data))
    else:
        for part_header in part_headers:
            part_header_name = part_header.get("name")
            part_header_value = part_header.get("value")
            if part_header_name == "Content-Disposition":
                if "attachment" in part_header_value:
                    attachment_id = body.get("attachmentId")
                    attachment = service.users().messages() \
                        .attachments().get(id=attachment_id, userId='me', messageId=message['id']).execute()
                    data = attachment.get("data")
                    filepath = os.path.join(folder_name, filename)
                    if data:
                        with open(filepath, "wb") as f:
                            f.write(urlsafe_b64decode(data))

def get_size_format(b, factor=1024, suffix="B"):
    for unit in ["", "K", "M", "G", "T", "P", "E", "Z"]:
        if b < factor:
            return f"{b:.2f}{unit}{suffix}"
        b /= factor
    return f"{b:.2f}Y{suffix}"

def output_emails(service,msg):
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id = msg['id'],format = 'full').execute()
    payload = message['payload']
    headers = payload.get("headers")
    print(payload)
    parts = payload.get("parts")
    sender = ""
    subject = ""
    date = ""
    for header in headers:
        name = header.get("name")
        value = header.get("value")
        if name.lower() == "from":
            sender = value.split('<')[0].strip()
        if name.lower() == "subject":
            subject = value
        if name.lower() == "date":
            date = value

    f_name = f"{sender}_{subject}"
    f_name = safe_folder_name(f_name)

    f_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"emails",f_name)

    if not os.path.exists(f_path):
        os.makedirs(f_path)

    with open(os.path.join(f_path,"date.txt"),"w",) as file:
        file.write(date)

    output_parts(service,parts,f_path,message)
    
def safe_folder_name(text):
    return "".join(c if c.isalnum() else "_" for c in text)


def main():
    service = gmail_authenticate()
    unread_emails = get_unread_emails(service)
    for msg in unread_emails:
        output_emails(service,msg)
    ids = [email['id'] for email in unread_emails]
    mark_as_read(service,ids)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```